# Filter a custom field based on selection of another custom field (ACF)

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, advanced-custom-fields

I have 3 custom post types with Advanced Custom Fields:

- Student
- Class
- Homework Assignment

**Homework** has a custom field that is a 'relationship' with **Class**. This is because specific pieces of homework are related to specific classes.

A **Student** has a relationship field with **Class** because each student is part of a class.

Now I want to create a **Homework Assignment**, so I set a custom field (relationship) of **student**. Once I've chosen a student, I want the 2nd custom field (also a relationship) to give me the choice of any **Homework Assignment** records that have the same **class** as the **student**.

So basically how do I have a conditional statement with Advanced Custom Fields that 'filters' instead of 'show/hides' the 2nd custom field?

Comment: What have you already tried? Showing your research and efforts is prerequisite to asking questions here.

Comment: And have you [tried their support forums](http://support.advancedcustomfields.com/)?

Comment: ACF can do what you're looking to do.  It's great.  I'm not clear on what you want.  Do you want to see this relationship when editing a student or are you trying to display the relationship on the front end?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you're using the wrong tool to represent relations between posts. the custom post meta fields api is somehow inefficient for that task and has certain restrictions.

I advice to have a look at the "posts to posts" plugin from pipin which is much more suited for that task.